# Low water pressure for water filter cartridges

Tags: water, water-pressure, filter, water-filtration, water-purification

[image: Water filters]

Will these filters still work on Low Water Pressure?
These are the standard 10 inch filters.
I know that overpressure can render the filters useless.
but how about low pressure? will it still work?
let say 0.48 MPa or 69.61 PSI, around 3.5L per minute flow rate. will the filters still work properly?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Since we can't even read the manufacturer's name in your picture, the best we could do is guess. Have you looked at the mfgr's information about them? What do they say the working range is? If they require a minimum pressure above what your system can supply, then odds are good they won't work well for you. If that's the case you should contact the mfgr and ask _them_ if they'll be OK at a lower pressure, or find a different make/model of filter that will work at your available pressure.

Comment: @FreeMan, you're right. 
i might need to call the manufacturer cuz there's no info said on the cartridges :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use those same type filters on my kitchen cold water supply to filter out the chlorine taste in the water. This is where we get all our drinking water and water to make coffee. The water pressure in my home is between 70 and 75 psi. I replace the filter once per year.

Comment: I would expect the filters to work well even below 40 psi you may need to change them more often as pressure drop will reduce the water flow to a low flow when they are plugged up. On a well they should be changed more often because there is no chlorine to kill the things that grow but they work fine. +